# Postgres Generation json tree

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  lvl_1 TEXT NOT NULL,
  lvl_2 TEXT NOT NULL,
  lvl_3 TEXT NOT NULL,
  lvl_4 TEXT NOT NULL,
  lvl_5 TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

I need to get json:

```
{lvl_1:{lvl_2:{lvl_3:{lvl_4:{lvl_5}}}}}
```

At the moment i am doing so: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0efdd/8)

I get what I need, but is there a more elegant solution? There are 3 sub-queries in the query right now - I think this greatly affects performance!

Is it possible to do without nested queries?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you really want this multi-level nesting, then one way or another you need as many nested subqueries...

Comment: Yes, I need exactly 5 levels of nesting and get structured json at the output.  I read and looked for how to do this - this sql structure is so far my only solution.